# mysql order by case when

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get specific sorting with mysql. here is the table I have

```
id      fb_id   ...   date_added
1       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:15:00
2       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:16:00
3       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:17:00
4       2222222222    2013-04-15 14:18:00
5       3333333333    2013-04-15 14:19:00
6       4444444444    2013-04-15 14:20:00
7       2222222222    2013-04-15 14:21:00
8       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:22:00
```

What I am expecting is to sort by fb_id 111111111 and 2222222222 first then the rest in latest date order like this...

```
id      fb_id   ...   date_added
1       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:22:00
2       2222222222    2013-04-15 14:21:00
3       2222222222    2013-04-15 14:18:00
4       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:17:00
5       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:16:00
6       1111111111    2013-04-15 14:15:00
7       4444444444    2013-04-15 14:20:00
8       3333333333    2013-04-15 14:19:00
```

SQL I'm trying:

```
SELECT `id`, `fb_id`, `date_added` from MyTable
ORDER BY case when fb_id in (1111111111,2222222222) then -1 else date_added end, date_added desc
```

It sorted by fb_id first but the rest data are not sorted by the 'date_added desc'? Please help..

Comment: why are there still `1111111111` after `2222222222`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sorting by `date_added` in ascending order first due to your `ELSE` clause. Try:

```
ORDER BY case when fb_id in (1111111111,2222222222) then 0 else 1 end, 
    date_added desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Solutions which use row-based functions should be looked at circumspectly, they sometimes cause problems when you try to scale up.

If your table remains relatively small, that shouldn't be a problem but, if you're concerned, you can try something like:

```
select 1 as seq, id, fb_id, date_added
    where fb_id in (1111111111,2222222222)
union all select 2 as seq, id, fb_id, date_added
    where fb_id not in (1111111111,2222222222)
order by seq, fb_id, date_added desc
```

This results in two queries to the DBMS but this can often be faster than having to perform extra processing on each row of the result set before ordering.

As with all solutions, you should measure the impact rather than guessing, and do it with representative data.

Comment: I don't think my table gonna be so large but this might be the better way if it ever does thanks!